# Compile individual importable modules in Nuitka?

Tags: python, cython, nuitka

With Cython, you could compile individual modules of your code, and import and use those modules from the rest of your (interpreted) python code the way you would with any other module.

Is that possible in Nuitka?

Also, lets say that my project has a `main.py` that contains driver code/program entry point and user made modules `a.py`, `b.py` and `c.py`.

During development, say I compiled modules `a.py`, `b.py` and `c.py` (in the manner suggested above) and then kept working on `main.py` while importing the compiled versions of modules `a.py`, `b.py` and `c.py`.

After I'm done, I now wish to compile `main.py` too.

Will I have to compile `a.py`, `b.py`, `c.py` and `main.py` all over again so that Nuitka can package them into one executable.

Or can I just compile `main.py` and `main` can use the already compiled `a.so`, `b.so` and `c.so` modules just like `main.py` did, requiring me just to bundle them together?

In fact, I'd greatly prefer the latter workflow. Is it possible with Nuitka?